# Migrating content from Tridion 2009 to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: content-porter-2009, content-porter-2013-sp1

As part of upgrade from 2009 to 2013 SP1 for Tridion

- We will have an environment for users where they will have to
  enter/update content in both versions (2009 and 2013 CMS) for a short
  10 day window until the CDS is rolled out for 2013.
- Initially we thought to use Content Porter 2013 to migrate the
  content entered in 2009, but got confirmation from SDL that it is not
  possible to use Content Porter 2013.

This is a common scenario for many upgrade projects, has anyone else got around this problem?

One option would be to develop a custom Content Porter that takes the zip package from Content Porter 2009 and converts it to make it compatible with Content Porter 2013 SP1, but would require a lot of development effort to change all the xml files.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways you can approach this:

1: assuming your data model stays same in terms of schema, you can write custom content migration utility which will pick up data from an old version and then create components pages etc using core service with the data you want to migrate to the new version.

2: you can do an in-place upgrade to 2011 SP 1 first on one of your environment servers which has actual content and then content port from there to all the new version environment servers. AFAIR, you can content port from 2011 SP 1 to 2013. Please check regarding in place upgrade from 2009 to 2011 with Tridion, but I think that should be feasible

I would recommend option 2. Also, I would suggest to keep upgrades up to date to get benefits of new features in the product as well as getting continuous support from Tridion

Comment: Thanks Vipin. Yes option 2 sounds better. I will add details later about our exact solution.

Comment: If you're considering upgrading 2009 to 2011, why not go all the way to 2013 then?

Comment: Hi Nuno, my approaches are based on an out of place upgrade, hence I just want to go to a version which is supported by the latest version rather than going to the latest version for the current setup (2009). Once we reach to a supported/compatible version, then doing content porting from existing to the new environment servers becomes easy.

Comment: Also, out of place upgrades are far better when we run out of straight upgrade options (like 2009 to 2013 SP1 isn't). For various reasons like organization dependencies, n number of approvals, consumers of the application and their impact and continuous support, no longer duration downtimes for the consumers, better shaped environments (since everything will be latest) etc.